# How to tell if a printer driver supports GDI AlphaBlend?

Tags: c++, printing, gdi

I'm using `AlphaBlend` function when I want to print an semi-transparent 32 bpp image over some other graphics on a paper, like I would do on screen.

This is working with some printers drivers but not with others. When this doesn't work, image is drawn with opaque (white) background and underneath text or graphics don't appear in image region.

Two drivers for the same printer give two differents results. I could differentiate them using the following code and the explanation below:

```
char technology[MAX_PATH] = {0};
int escapeCode = GETTECHNOLOGY;
if (ExtEscape(hdc, QUERYESCSUPPORT, sizeof(int), (LPCSTR) &escapeCode, 0, nullptr) > 0)
{
    if (ExtEscape(hdc, GETTECHNOLOGY, 0, nullptr, MAX_PATH, (LPSTR) technology) > 0)
    {
        return technology;
    }
}
```

In one hand, if `technology` contains `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06"`, `AlphaBlend` is working; on the other hand, `AlphaBlend` is not working when `technology` is `"ESC/P"`.

Is there a general way to detect this feature?

According to https://www.winvistatips.com/threads/trick-to-hooking-drvalphablend-in-printer-driver.178598, a printer driver supports `AlphaBlend` when:

- `DrvAlphaBlend` is implemented in driver DLL
- `HOOK_ALPHABLEND` is present in `DrvFuncTable`
- `HOOK_ALPHABLEND` is returned by `EngAssociateSurface`

How could I check using Win32 API (or by other means) if `DrvAlphaBlend` is supported?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.
did you solve it?

Comment: @SeongtaekOH AlphaBlend support cannot be determined this way as driver may report wrong values unrelated with device capabilities. You must blend foreground image with background before printing it.

Comment: that's right! However, using Alphablend is faster than doing it using the SRCAND option of Bitblt and StrechDIBit to blend with the foreground background. So if you support it, you want to use AlphaBlend and if not, you want to use Bitblt, but the distinction is not clear. Haven't you found the cutoff for whether or not AlphaBlend is supported yet?

Comment: As you said, the distinction is not clear: that why I was not able to use AlphaBlend on device, because I couldn't find any way to check if it was available. It happened once a device that indicated it was AlphaBlend-compatible was blending the foreground with a black background (due to no background surface on the printer).

Answer (score 0):

use `GetDeviceCaps` with `SHADEBLENDCAPS` then look after `SB_PIXEL_ALPHA` or so

Comment: Value returned by `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, SHADEBLENDCAPS)` is `NULL` in either case.

Comment: "For a printer, GetDeviceCaps returns whatever the printer reports."  . If you've done all right with `hdc`.

Comment: This is what I also read, but `SHADEBLENDCAPS` never returned other than `NULL` (or `SB_NONE`) with all printers and printer drivers I've tested, taking into account that `hdc` is a valid DC with which I already printed documents at the same time. This value is not reliable.

Comment: i didn't tested it. but ms did

Comment: you can do this: perform some research on that if printer supports blending what else options it has that others hasn't. and go after this instead

Comment: and how many printers you'd tested? or you just read that forum?

Comment: I tried on 2 printers (say "Canon" and "Epson") and 3 printer drivers (say "Canon-Driver", "Epson-Driver-XPS" and "Epson-Driver-ESCP"). AlphaBlend works on Canon printer using its single driver, and on Epson using Epson-Driver-XPS. AlphaBlend doesn't work on Epson using Epson-Driver-ESCP. So one printer gives two different results depending on driver used.